# NSMutableArray sorting - case insensitive

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssortdescriptor

I am sorting an `NSMutableArray` as follows:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:str_key ascending:bool_asc_desc] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [ads_printers_array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

The problem is that this is case sensitive, and I would like to make it case insensitive. How can I do that? I tried reading the docs and found something like this:

```
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:str_key ascending:bool_asc_desc selector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare)] autorelease];
```

However, I have no idea what I should be putting in the selector argument. Thanks!

Comment: Checkout following post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5542888/200272

Comment: Thank you, for anyone interested the selector method that I used is (localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:). Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to sort an array using NSSortDescriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542762/i-want-to-sort-an-array-using-nssortdescriptor)

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  (Is *anything* in Objective-C straightforward..?!)

Answer (score 49):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:str_key 
    ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

ads_printers_array = [ads_printers_array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray 
    arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift, do the following:

`let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortDescriptorKey, ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))`