# NSSortDescriptor/NSPredicate to organize my tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

i have a table view. In the table view, there is a custom `UILabel`, And each label with have a letter. "A, B, C, D" etc.. You can hit a plus button on the nav bar and it bring you to another view controller to enter info, and you hit save, and it adds the row onto the table view. Is there a way to utilize `NSSortDescriptor`/`NSPredicate` to make all the "A"'s together (together meaning i want all the cells with a to be with each other, but i still want them in the same section. ) if that makes sense! Is there a way to do this? Im using `Core Data` to save all my information. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: NSPredicate is used to filtered data not for sorting prupose. you can use NSSortDescriptor for this. please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542762/i-want-to-sort-an-array-using-nssortdescriptor

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `NSFetchedResultsController`. If not, please refactor and do.

The section grouping is anyway taken care of by the key path during the initialization of the fetched results controller with the argument `sectionKeyPath`.

As the sorting does not change, simply add a sort descriptor to the fetch request before initializing the fetched results controller:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor 
       sortDescriptorWithKey:@"textAttributeName" ascending:YES]];
```

where textAttributeName is the whatever you called your A B C label attribute in your entity.