# CoreData localized sorting

Tags: swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I need to sort data in CoreData entity containing special national characters. I have NSSortDescriptor as follows

```
let sorting = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Books.bokName, ascending: true)]
```

and found hint here [iPhone CoreData - How to fetch managed objects, and sorting them ignoring case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013158/iphone-coredata-how-to-fetch-managed-objects-and-sorting-them-ignoring-case)
Unfortunately it seems that newer vesrion of Swift included in XCode 12.3 doesn`t support selector parameter anymore. What other options I have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - Sorting an array retrieved from Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649464/swift-sorting-an-array-retrieved-from-core-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I realized that I have to use

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "bokName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
```

instead of init with keyPath.